# Android: How to get back to main activity after click?

Tags: android, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I am beginner in android and I have question how to get result from other activity and back to my main activity:

Example from my project:
I have some main activity ... when I click on button, application will open activity where is only list. After user click on some item from list, I need back open my main activity and display data from that item. How can I do that ?

Comment: You should look for startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` .
Have a look here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html